# Setting only background color of MainWindow Qt

Tags: qt

So I am trying to change only the background color of my `MainWindow`. When I try to do this using `this->setStyleSheet("background-color:black;");` for example it changes the background of everything: child widgets, `QTextBoxEdit` background, everything.

Is there a way to only change the background of just the main window?

Answer (score 4):

you can use Qt class name before QSS, like 
`QMainWindow { background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}`

in your example `QMainWindow > QWidget { background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}` maybe better.

please see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html for more information

Answer (score 4):

As you know, every `QMainWindow` has a central widget and by default is named `centralwidget`.

So the best way of solving this issue is changing the background for that widget.

It's pretty simple when we use a style sheet. In this case would be the following one:

```
#centralwidget {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```