# QGridLayout not affected by styleSheet

Tags: python, pyqt

Using Qt Designer I created GUI for my project. Added: groupBox which has gridLayout with few QLabels and QtextEdits.

I changed color of groupBox with this(using styleSheet):

```
QGroupBox 
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.502, y1:1, x2:0.493, y2:0, 
                                stop:0 rgba(10, 15, 73, 255), 
                                stop:1 rgba(30, 46, 223, 255));
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;   
    color: rgba(254,195,59,255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    font: 75 11pt "Candara";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and this to each element, so background of labels and text edits will be transparent(and have the color of GroupBox):

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
color: rgba(254,195,59,255);
font: 75 11pt "Candara";
font-weight: bold;
```

it looks like I want, but, when I press CTRL+R, grouplayout with labels and textEdits has the same color as background of window.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FyCM.png) and [What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ2zn.png). What I'm doing wrong? Minimal reproducible example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(542, 268)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 511, 211))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane\n"
"{    \n"
"    border: 1px solid; /*граница*/\n"
"    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QTabWidget::tab-bar\n"
"{    \n"
"    left: 10px; /*перемещение кнопок вкладок*/\n"
"    width: 500px;\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab\n"
"{        \n"
"    font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.502, y1:1, x2:0.493, y2:0, \n"
"                                stop:0 rgba(10, 15, 73, 255), \n"
"                                stop:1 rgba(30, 46, 223, 255));\n"
"    border-top-left-radius: 4px;\n"
"    border-top-right-radius: 4px;\n"
"    min-width: 8px;\n"
"    padding: 5px;    \n"
"    border: 1px solid;\n"
"    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab:selected, \n"
"QTabBar::tab:hover\n"
"{\n"
"    background-color: rgb(95, 80, 145);\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab:!selected\n"
"{\n"
"    margin-top: 5px\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab:selected\n"
"{\n"
"    margin-left: 4px;\n"
"    margin-right: 4px;\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.502, y1:1, x2:0.493, y2:0, \n"
"                                stop:0 rgba(17, 27, 130, 255),\n"
"                                stop:1 rgba(33, 51, 250, 255));\n"
"}")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.groupBox_3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.widget)
        self.groupBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 391, 121))
        self.groupBox_3.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox \n"
"{\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.502, y1:1, x2:0.493, y2:0, \n"
"                                stop:0 rgba(10, 15, 73, 255), \n"
"                                stop:1 rgba(30, 46, 223, 255));\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    padding: 5px;    \n"
"    color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.groupBox_3.setObjectName("groupBox_3")
        self.layoutWidget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.groupBox_3)
        self.layoutWidget_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 371, 81))
        self.layoutWidget_6.setObjectName("layoutWidget_6")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.gridLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_7, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit_SR_N = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget_6)
        self.textEdit_SR_N.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.textEdit_SR_N.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"border: nonde;")
        self.textEdit_SR_N.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit_SR_N.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_SR_N.setObjectName("textEdit_SR_N")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.textEdit_SR_N, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_34 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_34.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_34.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_34.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.label_34.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.label_34.setObjectName("label_34")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_34, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit_SB_N = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_SB_N.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setObjectName("textEdit_SB_N")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.textEdit_SB_N, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_36 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_36.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_36.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_36.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.label_36.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.label_36.setObjectName("label_36")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_36, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit_CVR_N = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_CVR_N.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setObjectName("textEdit_CVR_N")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.textEdit_CVR_N, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_26 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_26.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_26.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_26.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.label_26.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.label_26.setObjectName("label_26")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_26, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.layoutWidget_6)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.textEdit_CVWL_N.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(118, 36))
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"color: rgba(254,195,59,255);\n"
"font: 75 11pt \"Candara\";\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setObjectName("textEdit_CVWL_N")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.textEdit_CVWL_N, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.widget, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 542, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox_3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Repetability"))
        self.label_7.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">SR</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_34.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">SB</p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_SB_N.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Candara\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:12pt; font-weight:400;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_36.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">%CVR</p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_CVR_N.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Candara\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:12pt; font-weight:400;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_26.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">%CVWL</p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.textEdit_CVWL_N.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Candara\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:600; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:12pt; font-weight:400;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.widget), _translate("MainWindow", "Level N"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Upd. Found that this problem occurre when I change color of centralWidget `background-color: rgb(170, 255, 255);`

Comment: I had trouble setting stylesheets in a table widget too. My workaround was just to apply it to each item inside, which did actually work fine.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to just use layouts by dragging them from the widget box. Those layouts are intended only for **nesting** (adding a nested layout to an existing one). Don't do that, unless you *really* know what you're doing. In order to properly set a layout for a widget container (including the top level window), you have to right click on an empty area inside it (not on a child parent!) and select a proper layout from the "Lay out" submenu. Read the documentation about [Using Layouts in Qt Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: Note that, while the accepted answer *might* work, your usage of widgets and stylesheets may result in further issues in the future. For future reference: 1. please post the UI code instead of the pyuic generated code (so that we can open it in Designer, instead of trying to understand it by studying the whole code); 2. remember that QSS (Qt Style Sheets), like CSS, are *cascading*, meaning that they have effects on their *child* objects; 3. QSS are not the *exact* match of CSS, they are only *based* on them (and also supporting the CSS2.1 implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use this on MainWindow:

```
QMainWindow > QWidget { background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}
```

[Setting only background color of MainWindow Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439244/setting-only-background-color-of-mainwindow-qt)